# convert dynamically loaded textarea to tinyMCE

Tags: ajax, tinymce, textarea

I'm looking for how to set up a tinymce to a textarea that has been loaded using the AJAX.

I use TinyMCE 4.0.2 (minified), and I have found this method:

```
var ed = tinymce.get('content');
//ed.init();
ed.render();
//ed.focus();
```

Via this page: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.Editor

The code comments are other solutions I tested alone or combined with no other result

This changes are almost correct, the textarea well but it is inaccessible, i can't edit it.

I even tried to create a new tinymce via this method:

```
var ed = new tinymce.Editor('content');
```

But it does not work (TypeError: r is undefined).

And finally, I even tested old code like this:

```
tinymce.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "content");
```

But I'm still in check

So I'm stuck at the moment, would you know how to correct my mistake?
I use JQuery but I do not use the plugin tinymce.jquery, I want to be free to change JS framework.
But obviously the case, I've tried this code (via http://fiddle.tinymce.com/rsdaab):

```
$('#content').tinymce();
```

That does not work either.
Here is the JS code I use:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/admin/post/new',
    type:'get'
})
    .done(function(data) {
        $('#main').html(data);
        var ed = tinymce.get('content');
        ed.render();
    });
```

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a function:

```
    function tinyMceLoader(tinyMceID) {
    var ed = new tinymce.Editor(tinyMceID,
            {
                mode: "textareas",
                theme: "advanced",
                skin: "o2k7",
                directionality: "rtl",
                plugins: "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
                // Theme options
                theme_advanced_buttons1: "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor",
                theme_advanced_buttons2: "search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage,|,print",
                theme_advanced_buttons3: "ltr,rtl,|,tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,backcolor",
                theme_advanced_buttons4: "",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "right",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
                theme_advanced_resizing: true
            },
    tinymce.EditorManager);
    ed.render();
}
```

Then:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/admin/post/new',
    type:'get'
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (e) {
                  //some code ....
                  tinyMceLoader('content');        
             }
    });
```